# Nested for loops. How do I optimize this?

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization

I'm currently working on an approval system right now using **PHP (Codeigniter)** and I have this method of getting all the request according to your department group and position depth.

The checking of the requests is based upon the user's position depth. 6 being the lowest and 1 being the highest. So basically there will be a maximum of 5 people to check the request. For example my depth is 6, line1 will be 5, line2 will be 4 and so on. The system will find someone with position depths like that and same department group. Lines 3 and 2 will decide to send it to ceo (1) or not so the default is only until 2.

**Some of my database columns**
[image: Some database columns]

It is designed that people above the line can check the request even if the lower lines havent checked it yet like for example maybe line1 havent checked it yet because he/she is on vacation and line3 cannot wait already so he/she decides to process the request because it is important. **Now if the above line processes it already, lower lines cannot process it anymore so they will only be allowed to view it.**

Now here comes my code of nested `for` loops in checking out all these things that I said. People say nested `for` loops, especially as many as mine is not a good practice. How do I alter my code without altering my database for this?

**This is my Model**

```
public function getRequestsToProcess($i,$depth,$departmentGroup)
{
    $this->db->select('*, ns_request_info.idx as request_idx, ns_staff_info.idx as staff_idx');    
    $this->db->from('ns_request_info');
    $this->db->join('ns_staff_info', 'ns_request_info.requested_by_idx = ns_staff_info.member_idx');
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'', $depth);
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'_action', 'PENDING');
    if($departmentGroup!='HIGHER TIER'){ $this->db->where('ns_staff_info.department_group', $departmentGroup); }
    $this->db->where('status', 'PENDING');
    $this->db->or_where('status', 'ONGOING');
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'', $depth);
    $this->db->where('line'.$i.'_action', 'PENDING');
    if($departmentGroup!='HIGHER TIER'){ $this->db->where('ns_staff_info.department_group', $departmentGroup); }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**This is my method with nested `for` loops**

```
public function process()
{
    $data = new stdClass;
    $data->param_menu = 'request';

    $staffInfo = $this->staffinfo_model->selectItem(array('member_idx'=>$this->session->userdata('member_index')));

    for ( $i=1 ; $i<=5 ; $i++) {
        /*get lines with user depth and if same department group*/
        ${"line" . $i} = $this->staffrequisition_model->getRequestsToProcess($i,$staffInfo->position_depth,$staffInfo->department_group);

        for ($x = 0 ; $x < count(${"line" . $i}) ; $x++) {
            $counter = 0;
            for ($y = $i + 1 ; $y <=5 ; $y++) {
                if (${"line" . $i}[$x]['line'.$y.'_action']!=='PENDING' && ${"line" . $i}[$x]['line'.$y.'_action']!=='') {
                    $counter++;
                    break; 
                } 
            }
            if ($counter > 0) {
                ${"line" . $i}[$x]['is_checked'] = 1;
            } else {
                ${"line" . $i}[$x]['is_checked'] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    $data->param_requests = array_merge($line1, $line2, $line3, $line4, $line5);

    $this->load->view('dashboard/staff/process_view', $data);
}
```

Now `is_checked` being the marker if the request is already checked in upper lines. I hope you guys can give me any tips on how to optimize my code.

Comment: Suggestion: put this on stack's code review. That's more for this type of question.

Comment: @Alex sorry my bad. Im going to post this in code review. Code review said I can post after 40 minutes.

Comment: I've flagged the mod to move it for you but you can also do so and maybe it will happen quicker. Not to familiar with the migration procceses.

Comment: @Alex code review said I can post after 40 minutes so I guess I have to wait.

Comment: @Alex posted it already in code review mate.